# Python import - Module not found

Tags: python

I am following a Flask tutorial (on Pluralsight). I have come to where I need to initialize a database, using Flask-SQLalchemy. In the tutorial this is done via the following command, inside Python:

```
from PyBook.PyBook import db
from PyBook.PyBook.Models import Company
```

(Actually the names are different in the tutorial, but the concept is very much the same)

However, when I try to run the commands above, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File <stdin>, line 1, in <module> 
File  "C:\Users\Jakob-Desktop\source\repos\PyBook\PyBook\PyBook.py", line 3, in <module
from forms.add_company import AddCompanyForm 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forms'
```

Which suggests that the error is in either PyBook.py or add_company (which is referenced by PyBook, as you can see below).

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? I am kind of new to Python.

**PyBook.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from forms.add_company import AddCompanyForm
import secrets, os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = secrets.token_urlsafe(16)

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqllite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'pybook.db')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

(...)
```

**add_company.py**

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields import StringField
from wtforms.fields.html5 import URLField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, url

class AddCompanyForm(Form):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

**Update**

As far as I can tell, the folder structure is correct:

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Did you mean to import `FlaskForm`?

Comment: You're trying to import something from the `forms` folder and Python is not being able to find it. Is it there?

Comment: From a super quick cursory look, I'd say `add_company` should sit in a folder `forms`. And that folder should have an empty `__init__.py` to designate it as a module.

Comment: As far as I can tell I got the folder structure setup correct. But I have added a screenshot, so you can see for yourself.

Comment: Add an empty `__init__.py` inside forms. If it doesn't work try importing `.forms.add_company`.

Comment: It appears that if I go to the `./PyBook/PyBook/` directory before start python.exe, then I can do `from PyBook import db`. No clue why I can do it from a folder deeper though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `from .forms.add_company import AddCompanyForm` as a '.' is used to go through the current directory.

Comment: If I do that I get an error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the 'forms' folder is not in the PYTHONPATH. If you ever want to look at what is in the PYTHONPATH, you could use:

```
import sys

print(sys.path)
```

You need to add a file (usually empty but not always) called `__init__.py` in the forms folder. I normally would also add one in the main PyBook folder.

Here is a great guide to understanding how imports work:

[Definite Guide To Python Imports](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html)

Alternatively, you could also add this to the top of your code in PyBook.py

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'forms'))
```

If you were to add the code, you won't have to do something like:

```
from forms.add_company import AddCompanyForm
```

but you could just use:

```
from add_company import AddCompanyForm
```